# New 7 Install, ipconfig/release/renew brings LAN connection, but temporarily

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lan

I am new to this forum. I appreciate any help you can offer.

I have been troubleshooting an error with both my WIRED Internet Connection and AUDIO since installing Windows 7, over a previously running XP OS on the same Comp.

I have 3 desktops running through this working connection (Router) with no problems. If I connect directly to the Modem, no problem on the internet.

Through the Router, my computer connects for a period of time but if ever awaking my comp, or restarting, the yellow explanation mark returns.

The only way I can get the connection up = cmd. ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew. This constant command is annoying and was hoping for a permanent fix.

Audio is also not working. I know its likely a driver error, but its an old comp we put together and if there's an easy fix itd be great to hear from you! If you need any more info just let me know. Thanks!

THanks guys!

Comment: Both these issues sound like driver problems.  Have you tried updating the drivers?

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. I havent yet. Is there a service pack I can download for 7 or do I need to OEM's individual ones?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

Have you tried using the automated troubleshooter? It may (or may not) be an address conflict. You can do this by right clicking the network icon in the notification area and click troubleshoot problem. This will automatically repair the problem and report what was done.

I am assuming that your windows 7 PC is using DHCP to get it's address while the other computers have a static address. Thus the problem *should* occur when you do the following:

1. turn off all PC
2. turn on your windows 7 PC
3. put windows 7 PC to sleep
4. turn on the other three computers
5. wake windows 7 PC

If I am correct, this is how you fix it:

1. turn off all computers
2. turn on the other three computers
3. after all three computers have access to internet, turn on windows 7 computer
4. In your windows 7 PC, go to your network connections and [check the current IP address](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-PH/windows-vista/Find-your-computers-IP-address)
5. [assign this address as it's static address](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-PH/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings)

basically what you did was assign a unique static address to that computer.

I apologize for the long answer, your question simply lacks information to work with.

**Problem 2**

As for the audio problem, we're gonna need more information than "Audio does not work".

To confirm whether or not this is a driver problem, [you should check the device manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Open-Device-Manager)

If you see your audio device has a problem, [you can try using the automated troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-PH/windows7/Open-the-Hardware-and-Devices-troubleshooter). This may or may not download and install a driver. If it doesn't, you have no choice but to go to the manufacturer's website and download the latest driver.